# \IfFileExists is acting inconsistently when testing another boolean in conjunction with \input

Tags: conditionals

I've been refactoring some code and clearing out obsolete commands.

I don't understand what's happening here:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mkif}
\newif\ifaeRoughDraft
\def\testforRoughDraft
  {\ifaeRoughDraft
    \lfoot{testing}
    \rfoot{proof}
    \fi
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\IfFileExists{.ae.proof}
  {
    \input{mkif}
    \IfFileExists{.ae.draft}
      {\aeRoughDrafttrue}
      {}
    \testforRoughDraft
    %%\ifaeRoughDraft\lfoot{testing}\rfoot{proof}\fi
  }{}

\begin{document}

testing

\end{document}
```

Assuming you create `.ae.proof` and `.ae.draft`, the MWE as provided above compiles fine.  However, if you try to compile

```
\begin{filecontents}{mkif}
\newif\ifaeRoughDraft
\def\testforRoughDraft
  {\ifaeRoughDraft
    \lfoot{testing}
    \rfoot{proof}
    \fi
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\IfFileExists{.ae.proof}
  {
    \input{mkif}
    \IfFileExists{.ae.draft}
      {\aeRoughDrafttrue}
      {}
    %%\testforRoughDraft
    \ifaeRoughDraft\lfoot{testing}\rfoot{proof}\fi
  }{}

\begin{document}

testing

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
! Extra \else.
\IfFileExists ...ileonpath {#1}{#2}{#3}}\fi \else 
                                                  \closein \@inputcheck \ede...
l.22       }{}
```

It seems to me the code is equivalent.  But, obviously LaTeX doesn't think so.

If I change how I input the file `mkif`---such as removing it from within the `\IfFileExists`---things work once more regardless of when I use `\testforRoughDraft` or `\ifaeRoughDraft`.

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in the second argument of `\IfFileExists` is absorbed before `\input{mkif}` is executed and the `\fi` is thus paired improperly to a conditional deriving from the expansion of `\IfFileExists`. Let's see.

The expansion of

```
\IfFileExists{.ae.proof}
  {
    \input{mkif}
    \IfFileExists{.ae.draft}
      {\aeRoughDrafttrue}
      {}
    \ifaeRoughDraft\lfoot{testing}\rfoot{proof}\fi
  }{}
```

is

```
\openin\@inputcheck .ae.proof
\ifeof\@inputcheck
  \ifx\input@path\@undefined
    \def\reserved@a{}%
  \else
    \def\reserved@a{%
      \@iffileonpath{.ae.proof}%
      {\input{mkif}\IfFileExists{.ae.draft}{\aeRoughDrafttrue}{}%
       \ifaeRoughDraft\lfoot{testing}\rfoot{proof}\fi}{}}%
  \fi
\else
  \closein\@inputcheck
  \edef\@filef@und{.ae.proof }%
  \def\reserved@a{%
    \input{mkif}\IfFileExists{.ae.draft}{\aeRoughDrafttrue}{}%
    \ifaeRoughDraft\lfoot{testing}\rfoot{proof}\fi
  }%
\fi
\reserved@a
```

Since `.ae.proof` is found, the "true" branch of `\ifeof` is skipped; it's the first `\fi` that is seen to stop this branch and it is the wrong one. So the next `\fi` ends the true branch of `\ifeof` and an extra `\else` is scanned. The error message tells precisely that the extra `\else` comes just before `\closein`.

TeX doesn't keep track of braces when skipping text in a conditional. And it's not sufficient that a control sequence starts with `\if...` to be considered a conditional: only control sequences `\let` to a primitive conditional are marked with a special flag that makes TeX pair them with `\else` or `\fi` when skipping tokens in a branch of a conditional. So, until `\newif\ifaeRoughDraft` is not executed, `\ifaeRoughDraft` is just an undefined control sequence.

In the other case, the `\fi` is not there, because TeX doesn't expand macros when skipping tokens in a conditional, so what's seen is just `\testforRoughDraft`.

---

A better way to proceed, but this a matter of opinions, is to always input `mkif`; thus you won't be risking a conditional to be undefined. Or use a better macro instead of `\testforRoughDraft`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mkif}
\newif\ifaeRoughDraft
\makeatletter
\newcommand\doifaeRoughDraft{%
  \ifaeRoughDraft
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\end{filecontents}
```

so that you can say

```
\IfFileExists{ae.proof}
  {\input{mkif}%
   \IfFileExists{ae.draft}{\aeRoughDrafttrue}{}%
   \doifaeRoughDraft{\lfoot{testing}\rfoot{proof}}{}%
  }{}
```

which is more flexible.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  From what you're saying, it seems like things shouldn't work whether or not `\input{mkif}` is present.

Comment: Also, are you suggesting that the only way I can hide the `\fi` from the overzealous reach of the expansion process is to bury it in a macro as in my first example?

Comment: @A.Ellett Yes, that's the trick.

Comment: @A.Ellett Tomorrow I'll add a different workaround.

Comment: I'll look forward to your answer.

Comment: I read this too quickly this morning.  Now I see what you're doing.  I like it.  :)  Regarding your suggestion to always input the file, that's not an option.  As I'm going through and refactoring old code, I periodically want to see what the *former* effects are and so load the old versions of the file.  I really wanted some control from the command line so I don't go in and tinker too much more than necessary in the files.